# How to change free downloaded theme default color in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-theme

I am a magento learner i have created a dummy website and installed free magento 1.9 theme692 from given link. 
https://www.templatemonster.com/free-templates/responsive-fashion-store-magento-theme-53078.html

Now I want to change default aqua color highlighted with red in given screenshot.

[image]

I have replaced the existing color with a new color code in `style.css` file but not take effect on frontend. Please guide me where can I change this colours according to my choice of colors?

Comment: Clear the browser cache, flush the magento cache and try again.

Comment: Hi Sukumar, Thanks now it is working but color is unchanged in header and banner slider.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLto9.png Please suggest how can i change header and banner slider icon color.

Comment: Did you use find and replace for that color?

Comment: Yes, i used the find and replace.

Comment: For banner slider you need to check camera.css and for logo you need to change the image.

Comment: i know logo i can change by replacing the image. My issue is header text is still showing in aqua color.

Comment: check by inspect element in your browser, select the element and it will show the applied css with file path and line number

Comment: You need to update the same on megamenu.css under skin/frontend/default/theme692/css/cmsmart/megamenu/megamenu.css

Comment: You can add your own css and attach it to theme via default_head_blocks.xml and add your css changes to it

Comment: @SukumarGorai, color changed but in header small arrow is still shoqwing in aqua color. How can i change this small arrow color.

Comment: Where can i found  .nav .grid-full > li.parent   sorry i am totally new with magento.

Comment: you can find it under megamenu.css

Comment: Hi, do the necessary changes but still small pointer is showing in aqua color.  .nav .grid-full > li.parent > a > span:after { 
  content: "\f107";
  display: inline-block; 
  font-size:15px; 
  color: #fd65b0; 
  border-radius: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 40%;